# Can methanol be oxidised by PCC?

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-oxidation

Pyridinium chlorochromate (PCC) in $\ce{CH2Cl2}$ can be used to oxidise primary alcohols only to aldehydes. I can't however, find any reference of it oxidising methanol (which is strictly speaking not a primary alcohol). My question is, does PCC oxidise methanol to formaldehyde and if not, what can I use to achieve this reaction?

Comment: My textbooks don't spend much time on reactions with methyl derivatives and I'm struggling to find brief discussions of 'methyl chemistry' that isn't on a higher level.

Comment: www.chem.libretexts.org/Textbook_Maps/Organic_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Map%3A_Organic_Chemistry_(Smith)/Chapter_12%3A_Oxidation_and_Reduction/12.07_Oxidizing_Agents

Comment: Yes it can. Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score -2):

Look at the examples given here:

[image]

(Ignore the stuff written with pen; I have a habit of taking notes when reading)

PCC is taking two hydrogen atoms – one from the carbon atom attached to the -OH group and the other one from the -OH group itself, and then making a C=O double bond. Methanol has both of these. So, PCC should be able to oxidise it to formaldehyde.